# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError (VueJS with OpenWeatherMap API)

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, web-frontend

Im trying out a weather app with VueJS using the weathermap API. I already got my API key and I still doesn't work on my application. But when I try to use the link for the API in the browser, it shows data in it. But why it doesn't show data in my app. I checked the browser console it display an error `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Here is my code:

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
    return{
      api_key: 'f9874496f4c1c5729fc7b4f546b1ebe4',
      url_base: "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/",
      query: '',
      weather: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchWeather(e) {
      if(e.key == "Enter") {
        fetch(`${this.url_base}weather?q=${this.query}&units=metric&appid=${this.api_key}`)
        .then(res=> {
          return res.json();
        }).then(this.setResults);
      }
    },

    setResults (results) {
      this.weather = results;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is a photo of the API link I used in the browser.
[check it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO9Qg.png)

I hope someone could help me out with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error means that you get HTML instead of JSON. You didn't specify the protocol and do the request to your own domain. Check this in network tab, you have it at hand.

Comment: What specifically will I do on the network tab? I am just new in web development

Comment: Then browser dev tools (F12) is your new best friend, and network tab is one of the tabs there, it allows to see what was sent and what was received. In this case it should show that you did a request to your own domain and not api.openweathermap.org and likely received index HTML from there. Good luck with it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll try to explore there.

Answer (score 0):

you need to catch your errors and print it to find out exactly what is wrong.

```
 fetch(`${this.url_base}weather?q=${this.query}&units=metric&appid=${this.api_key}`)
.then(res=> {
          return res.json();
        })
.then(this.setResults)
.catch(error=>console.log(error))
```

this should get rid of the uncaught(promise) error and print the actual error

Comment: What's printed is the exact error. `res.json()` causes it.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 0):

This must be from "Tyler Potts" Vue weather app tutorial on YouTube. I was stuck here too.

Your url_base needs to include http:// at the beginning:

```
url_base: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
```

### Edit

I believe this is because while we may be used to our browsers including the "http://" protocol at the beginning, so that all we need to do as users is type in the hostname and domain to access a website or data we wish to retrieve, our code will not automatically do the same. So you must specify exactly and fully what the function must fetch.

Comment: Hi nickalara, thanks for sharing a potential fix but it does not clearly explain why this change corrects the problem that what encountered by the user who asked the question.  Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of why this change to the original code will correct the problem.

Comment: Aossey, Please enlighten us.